# put session inside echo

Tags: javascript, php, session

```
 if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY1']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY1'] > 5)) {


         echo'
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var marks = <?php echo session_unset(); ?>
    var answer = confirm ("Your Session will expired.Click yes to continue or cancel to logout")
    if (answer){
    alert ("Woo Hoo! So am I.")

    }else{
    alert ("Darn. Well, keep trying then.")

// code need to put here is php

    }
    </script>
    ';
    }else{
    }
```

above is my current code.. now i want to insert session in echo else.. how to do this.. how to put php code in javascript in php echo ..

below is code inside else :

```
if (isset($_SESSION['member_id'])) {
      session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time
        session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage


      header('Location: '.AT_BASE_HREF.'login.php?loginexpired=true');
       exit;
  }
```

Comment: And what is your problem? What does not work? Beside that: how should the `<?php echo session_unset(); ?>`  in the string work?

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing. `session_unset()` doesn't return anything, why are you trying to echo it?

Comment: You can't use `<?php` inside strings, you can only use that when you've switched from PHP script interpretation to raw output.

Comment: because it in php.. i want to do popup ... if click yes it do nothing.. if no unset session

Answer (score 1):

When you're using `echo`, you need to use string concatenation, not `<?php` to execute PHP code. So it should be:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">

var marks = ' . session_unset() . ';
var answer = confirm ("Your Session will expired.Click yes to continue or cancel to logout");
    if (answer){
        alert ("Woo Hoo! So am I.");

    }else{
        alert ("Darn. Well, keep trying then.")
' . $some_php_var . '
}
</script>';
```

Or instead of using `echo`, you can switch out of PHP interpretation:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY1']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY1'] > 5)) {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var marks = <?php echo session_unset(); ?>;
    var answer = confirm ("Your Session will expired.Click yes to continue or cancel to logout");
    if (answer){
        alert ("Woo Hoo! So am I.");

    }else{
        alert ("Darn. Well, keep trying then.");

    <?php // code need to put here is php
    ?>

    }
    </script>
<?php 
} else{
}
```

You have other problems, though. `session_unset()` doesn't return anything, so it makes no sense to assign it to something. The above will result in the statement:

```
var marks = ;
```

which will cause a Javascript syntax error. I'm not sure what you're trying to do there, so I don't know what to change it to.

Comment: i try your second code but it not do alert insted it expired the session.  your first code in . $some_php_var .  can i cahnge to session_unset(); do i need to asign it to $var?

Comment: I think you  have some misunderstandings about how PHP and Javascript work. PHP runs on the server when you create the page, it can't be affected by the Javascript `if`.

Comment: `$some_php_var` can also be a PHP function. But it will be run when the page is created, and its result will be put into the Javascript.

Comment: does it means.. i cant unset_session in popup alert?

Comment: You need to use AJAX to send a request to PHP telling it to unset the session.

Comment: my code just now is .. if the session is 5 second.. it will popup a comfirm alert ..click yes will refresh the page (renew_session) ..click cancel will logout (session_end) .. have you do this before?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69643/discussion-between-airi-and-barmar).

Comment: Sorry, I need to go to sleep